Stuck on a step in a proof in Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis
I'm reading Avner Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis and I am getting stuck on a step in the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem 2.4.3 If a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of a.e. real-valued, measurable functions is Cauchy in measure, Then there is a measurable function $f$ and a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converges to $f$ almost uniformly.

Here is the proof up to the point where I am stuck:

Proof. For any positive integer $k$ there is an integer $n_k$ such that
$$\mu \left[ \left\{ x; |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \ge \frac{1}{2^k} \right\} \right] \quad \text{if $n,m \ge n_k$.}$$
We may assume that $n_1 < n_2 < \dotsm$. Then $\{f_{n_k}\}$ is an infinite subsequence of $\{f_n\}$. Let
$$E_k = \left\{ x; |f_{n_k}(x) - f_{n_{k+1}}(x)| \ge \frac{1}{2^k} \right\}, \quad F_m = \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty E_k.$$
Then
$$|f_{n_h}(x) - f_{n_j}(x)| < \frac{1}{2^{j-1}} \quad \text{if $x \in X - F_m$,} \quad j \ge h \ge m. \tag{1}$$
Thus, on each set $X - F_m$, $\{f_{n_j}\}$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence. . . .

It is the line marked (1) that I am having trouble with. If $j = h$ then this is obviously true, so consider the case $j > h$. I note that $x \in X - F_m$ implies
$$|f_{n_k}(x) - f_{n_{k+1}}(x)| < \frac{1}{2^k} \quad \text{for all $k \ge m$.}$$
Hence I would have thought the idea is to use the triangle inequality,
$$|f_{n_h} - f_{n_j}| \le |f_{n_h} - f_{n_{h+1}}| + |f_{n_{h+1}} - f_{n_j}| < \frac{1}{2^h} + |f_{n_{h+1}} - f_{n_j}|,$$
and so on. But this yields
$$|f_{n_h} - f_{n_j}| < \sum_{k=h}^{j-1} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{2^{j-h} - 1}{2^{j-1}},$$
which is not as tight a bound as that given by Friedman, and useless for what follows. What am I missing?

It should be $h$ instead of $j$:
$$|f_{n_h}(x) - f_{n_j}(x)| < \frac{1}{2^{h-1}} \quad \text{if $x \in X - F_m$,} \quad j \ge h \ge m.$$

Wow, it seems you are right. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!
